# how to change the background color of progress bar programmatically

Tags: android, progress-bar

i am working with default horizontal progress bar and i just want to change the color of progress bar at run time by this code.

```
progress_bar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

since my background color is black and i don't how to change the light red color to black at run time

Progress bar image after run time

[image]

i want to change the color of bar denoted by arrow

Comment: You may need to create a custom progress bar like this: [Custom ProgressBar](https://gist.github.com/Antarix/fb9947308c8d5e7eb658)

Comment: what if i have to do it in default is there any possible way